# How to force-update the container image of a Container Action?

Tags: github-actions

I went through the following steps to create a container action:

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-docker-container-action

It uses this code to create the image:

[image]

After 1st run, the workflow creates an image, and then the workflow uses the same image created, so the workflow runs much quicker.

The problem is that when I change the files inside the container (for example `entrypoint.sh` in the example link above), the container image is not being updated. It keeps using the older version of the file inside the outdated image.

How to force-update the container image of a Container Action?

Comment: Please add the YAML definition of the workflow, in which you're using the Docker action, to your question?

Comment: @riQQ, I expect the approach shold be general and independant of any specific YML code. As such, adding YML code would distract people from the correct approach.

Comment: But it is relevant. If you call your action with a SHA like `username/actionrepo@sha`, it won't include new changes. The same is true for tags, if you don't update the tag.